# Inequality $\tan(a)^b+\tan(b)^c+\tan(c)^a\geq \tan(a)^c+\tan(c)^b+\tan(b)^a$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, exponentiation

I have this to solve :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ and $a\geq b \geq c$ then :
>   $$\tan(a)^b+\tan(b)^c+\tan(c)^a\geq \tan(a)^c+\tan(c)^b+\tan(b)^a$$

I try to study the behavior of (with the condition on $a,b$):
$$\tan(a)^b-\tan(b)^a$$

And for $a\geq b$ and $a+b<1$ I think we have :

$$\tan(a)^b-\tan(b)^a\geq a^b-b^a$$

Unfortunatly we can't apply this directly because there is the cyclicity (order on $a$ and $b$)

On the other hand I suggest that we have :

For $a\geq b >0$ $\quad$ and $\frac{1}{3}\geq b>0$ and $a+b<1$ we get  :

$$2(\tan(a)^{\frac{1}{3}}-tan(b)^{\frac{1}{3}})\geq \tan(a)^b-\tan(b)^a$$

My conclusion is : this is this kind of inequality of $2$ variables wich makes the problem a little bit easier .

My question :Have you  nice proof of this fact ?

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Answer (score 2):

$a=b=c$ obviously works. From this position, you are allowed to increase $a$ and decrease $b$ and $c$. Suppose $a>\frac{1}{3}$ with $b=c < \frac{1}{3}$. Then the inequality is satisfied (you can try this for yourself).

Now let's consider the case $a\geq b \geq c$. We start by the $a>b=c$ inequality and reduce $c$, fixing $b$ and increasing $a$. (This will cover  every single case of $a \geq b \geq c$).

We may rewrite by removing $a$ for $1-b-c$:

$f(c) = \tan(1-b-c)^b +\tan(b)^c +\tan(c)^{1-b-c} - \tan(1-b-c)^c - \tan(c)^{b} -\tan(b)^{1-b-c}$.

Now we compute the derivative with respect to $c$, keeping $b$ as a  constant.

We note that $f'(c) \leq 0$ here thus the inequality still holds when $c$ is reduced. Hence we have our result.

Below is the proof that $f'(c) \leq 0$.

$f'(c)$ has 8 terms, labelled $t_1, ..., t_8$.

$t_1+t_6 \leq 0$

$t_2+t_8 \leq 0$.

$t_3+t_5 \leq 0$ (here we use that $x\tan^x(k)$ is an increasing function for $\tan(k)<1$)

$t_4+t_7 \leq 0$